# Jquery por algum motivo não grava todas as variáreis

Tags: jquery

Galera tenho esse Jquery que grava todas essas variaveis de um formulário em  asp.net mvc.
Meu problema é que ele não esta gravando todas as variáveis. Ele grava aproximadamente a metade. Ele esta parando em estado_civil_proprietario. Alguém sabe me dizer se esse tipo de Jquery tem limitação quanto a capacidade de variáveis?

```
function SalvarCliente() {
debugger;
//Segurado
var nome_segurado = $("#Nome_Segurado").val();
var email_segurado = $("#Email_Segurado").val();
var telefone_segurado = $("#Telefone_Segurado").val();
var cpf_segurado = $("#CPF_Segurado").val();
var data_nasc_segurado = $("#Data_Nasc_Segurado").val();
var sexo_segurado = $("#Sexo_Segurado:checked").val();


var estado_civil_segurado = $("#Estado_Civil_Segurado option:selected").text();
//Veículo
var uso_veiculo = $("#Uso_Veiculo option:selected").text();
var Marca = $("#MarcaId option:selected").text();
var Modelo = $("#ModeloId option:selected").text();
var Versao = $("#VersaoId option:selected").text();
var ano_fabricacao = $("#Ano_Fabricacao").val();
var ano_modelo = $("#Ano_Modelo").val();
var zero_km = $("#Zero_Km:checked").val();
var num_portas = $("#Num_Portas:checked").val();
var combustivel = $("#Combustivel option:selected").text();
var alarme = $("#Alarme:checked").val();
var anticolisao = $("#Anticolisao:checked").val();
var possui_veiculo = $("#Possui_Veiculo:checked").val();
var placa = $("#Placa").val();
var estado = $("#Estado option:selected").text();
//Proprietário
var confirm_prorietario = $("#Confirm_Proprietario:checked").val();
var nome_proprietario = $("#Nome_Proprietario").val();
var tipo_pessoa_proprietario = $("#quote_policyholder_owner_kind_cd:checked").val();
var cpf_proprietario = $("#quote_policyholder_attributes_owner_attributes_cpf").val();
var cnpj_proprietario = $("#quote_policyholder_attributes_owner_attributes_cnpj").val();
var data_nasc_proprietario = $("#Data_Nasc_Proprietario").val();
var sexo_proprietario = $("#Sexo_Proprietario").val();
var estado_civil_proprietario = $("#Estado_Civil_Proprietario option: selected").text();
var relacao_proprietario = $("#Relacao_Proprietario option: selected").text();
var confirm_condutor = $("#Confirm_Condutor:checked").val();
var relacao_condutor = $("#Relacao_Condutor option: selected").text();
var nome_condutor = $("#Nome_Condutor").val();
var cpf_condutor = $("#CPF_Condutor").val();
var data_nasc_condutor = $("#Data_Nasc_Condutor").val();
var sexo_condutor = $("#Sexo_Condutor:checked").val();
var estado_civil_condutor = $("#Estado_Civil_Condutor option: selected").text();
var profissao_condutor = $("#Profissao_Condutor").val();
var primeira_habilitação = $("#Primeira_Habilitação").val();
//Análise de Risco
var residencia = $("#Residencia option: selected").text();
var cep = $("#CEP").val();
var cep_veiculo = $("#CEP_Veiculo:checked").val();
var cep_veiculo_noite = $("#CEP_Veiculo_Noite").val();
var mais_veiculo_residencia = $("#Mais_Veiculo_Residencia option: selected").text();
var garagem = $("#Garagem:checked").val();
var km_uso = $("#Km_Uso option: selected").text();
var escola = $("#escola:checked").val();
var trabalho = $("#Trabalho:checked").val();
var residentes_entre17a25 = $("#Residentes_Entre17a25:checked").val();
var adicionar_condutor = $("#Adicionar_Condutor:checked").val();
var nome_condutor_adicional = $("#Nome_Condutor_Adicional").val();
var sexo_condutor_adicional = $("#Sexo_Condutor_Adicional:checked").val();
var relacao_condutor_adicional = $("#Relacao_Condutor_Adicional option: selected").text();
//Finalizando
var possui_seguro = $("#Possui_Seguro:checked").val();
var forma_contato = $("#Forma_Contato:checked").val();
var token = $('input[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]').val();
var tokenadr = $('form[action="/Cliente/Create"] input[name="__RequestVerification"]').val();

var headers = {};
var headersadr = {};
headers['__RequestVerificationToken'] = token;
headersadr['__RequestVerificationToken'] = tokenadr;

var url = "/Cliente/Create";
$.ajax({
    url: url
    , type: "POST"
    , datatype: "json"
    , headers: headersadr
    , data: {
        Id: 0,
        Nome_Segurado: nome_segurado,
        Email_Segurado: email_segurado,
        Telefone_Segurado: telefone_segurado,
        CPF_Segurado: cpf_segurado,
        Data_Nasc_Segurado: data_nasc_segurado,
        Sexo_Segurado: sexo_segurado,
        Estado_Civil_Segurado: estado_civil_segurado,
        Uso_Veiculo: uso_veiculo, MarcaId: Marca,
        ModeloId: Modelo, VersaoId: Versao,
        Ano_Fabricacao: ano_fabricacao,
        Ano_Modelo: ano_modelo,
        Zero_Km: zero_km,
        Num_Portas: num_portas,
        Combustivel: combustivel,
        Alarme: alarme,
        Anticolisao: anticolisao,
        Possui_Veiculo: possui_veiculo,
        Placa: placa,
        Estado: estado,
        Confirm_Proprietario: confirm_prorietario,
        Nome_Proprietario: nome_proprietario,
        quote_policyholder_owner_kind_cd_1: tipo_pessoa_proprietario,
        quote_policyholder_attributes_owner_attributes_cpf: cpf_proprietario,
        CNPJ_Proprietario: cnpj_proprietario,
        Data_Nasc_Proprietario: data_nasc_proprietario,
        Sexo_Proprietario: sexo_proprietario,
        Estado_Civil_Proprietario: estado_civil_proprietario,
        Relacao_Proprietario: relacao_proprietario,
        Confirm_Condutor: confirm_condutor,
        Relacao_Condutor: relacao_condutor,
        Nome_Condutor: nome_condutor,
        CPF_Condutor: cpf_condutor,
        Data_Nasc_Condutor: data_nasc_condutor,
        Sexo_Condutor: sexo_condutor,
        Estado_Civil_Condutor: estado_civil_condutor,
        Profissao_Condutor: profissao_condutor,
        Primeira_Habilitação: primeira_habilitação,
        Residencia: residencia,
        CEP: cep,
        CEP_Veiculo: cep_veiculo,
        CEP_Veiculo_Noite: cep_veiculo_noite,
        Mais_Veiculo_Residencia: mais_veiculo_residencia,
        Garagem: garagem,
        Km_Uso: km_uso,
        Escola: escola,
        Trabalho: trabalho,
        Residentes_Entre17a25: residentes_entre17a25,
        Adicionar_Condutor: adicionar_condutor,
        Nome_Condutor_Adicional: nome_condutor_adicional,
        Sexo_Condutor_Adicional: sexo_condutor_adicional,
        Relacao_Condutor_Adicional: relacao_condutor_adicional,
        Possui_Seguro: possui_seguro,
        Forma_Contato: forma_contato,
        __RequestVerificationToken: token
    }
    , success: function (data) {
        if (data.Resultado > 0) {

        }
    }
});
```

}

Seque o codigo em C# da minha controller que manda as variáveis para o db:

```
[HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Create(Cliente cliente)
    {
      if (ModelState.IsValid)
      {

        db.Clientes.Add(cliente);
        db.SaveChanges();

      }




        return Json(new { Resultado = cliente.Id }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);



    }
```

Comment: Não pode haver espaço entre o `option:` e `selected`, por exemplo, nesta linha (e em outras): `$("#Estado_Civil_Segurado option: selected").text()`

Comment: Sera que é apenas isso man??? Nem acredito se for.

Comment: Não sei se é a causa do problema, mas já é um erro no código.

Comment: Era isso mesmo. kkkkk

Comment: Deixa eu perguntar. Gravar tudo isso dessa forma no db é ruim. Tem outro método melhor?

Comment: Tem o método .serialize() do jQuery, que já pega todo o formulário de uma vez.

Comment: mas esse método não tem que enviar pra uma pg em PHP pra depois mandar para o db?

Comment: Não necessariamente PHP... vc envia pro seu backend e grava no db

Comment: Tem algum exemplo com back-end em C#?

Comment: Vc envia da mesma forma que está enviado, tipo: `data: $('#myForm').serialize()`